# What is the alternative for '\f' char in Java?

Tags: java, page-break

I have an Application that writes some texts in a file . Each five lines must be in distinct page. I have to use `Dot Matrix Printers` that invoke continuous pages also I use `\f` for indicating new page. There is no problem in about writing file. But there is a problem when I print text file.

When printer prints first `\f` char , it invokes page completely without printing rest of the file. If I cut continuous page and insert them distinctly, all things will be good, but it is not a good way for printing files that have more than 100 pages. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to implement a page break as you would like is to insert unicode character 12, which is a form feed (FF) in ASCII and UTF. This will be interpreted by both Microsoft's Word and the WordPad application that ships with Windows, and a page break will be inserted correctly. You could achieve this in the following code:

```
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class PageBreakTest {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
        File f = new File("page.doc");  
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);  
        fw.write("Page 1 information" + (char)12);  
        fw.write("Page 2 after page break char");  
        fw.close();  
    }  
}
```